# Castle Windsor Generic Typed Factory

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, castle

On Kozmic's blog (dated 2009), he recommends a Generic Factory to retrieve objects from container. Well, this seems like a pseudo service locator to me. So I want to ask the opinion from experts here.

```
  public interface IGenericFactory
  {
        T Create<T>();
  }
```

Can I use this to fetch objects from Windsor container? Are there any downsides to this approach?

**Update:**

Actually, I want to use it to get only a few transients that I do not want to create multiple factories for. Having one factory for all such scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick Google search and found this article that you're probably referring to: http://kozmic.pl/2009/12/23/castle-typed-factory-facility-reborn/

If that's the case, then Krzysztof Koźmic says it himself:

> [...] with lit­er­ally no effort you can use it to build a *generic ser­vice locator*.

Yes, nowadays [Service Locator is considered to be an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

However, the article is about exceptional cases. The author puts it quite clearly in the first paragraph:

> Gen­eral rule of thumb when using IoC con­tain­ers is – when you’re ref­er­enc­ing your con­tainer in your com­po­nents (any­where out­side of your boot­strap­ping code) you’re doing it wrong. As with all rules there are excep­tions, but they are rare.

Comment: @w0lf-With the Generic factory approach, I do not have to reference the container in my code. I register it as a typed factory and boom. Inject the factory and get anything you want! (actually, I want to use it to get only a few transients that I do not want to create multiple factories for).I want to make sure this is good or bad thing?

Comment: @user1178376 the problem with that approach is that it's actually an Abstract Service Locator that can easily hide a class's dependencies. In order to avoid this and the maintenance problems it causes, try using plain constructor injection and specialized factories.

Comment: Also note the comment from Nicholas Blumhardt. He describes it quite clearly: "it could try to create literally anything - and this will make it harder to maintain and test.".

Answer (score 1):

Instead, consider the following:

```
public interface IGenericFactory<out T>
{
    T Create();
}
```

The interface only needs to be created once, but it must be injected for each service you need to resolve.  This way, it isn't a generic service locator (which is an antipattern, as previously mentioned by w0lf).

Bonus points:

Normal dependency injection requires that all services in your dependency graph can be resolved.  `IGenericFactory<>` will automatically be resolved via the typed factory facility.  But its generic type argument will not be resolved until executing `Create()`.

If that happens in an edge case deep in your program, and you forget to register the service, you might not realize the bug until production.

The solution is to write a custom resolver for `IGenericFactory<>` that checks whether the generic type argument has a handler and that it is not waiting for any dependencies to be registered.  Information about custom resolvers is here:  http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Resolvers.ash